# Send C# array to PHP web service using post

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I am trying to send this array `string[] str = { "abc" ,  "sdfsdf" };` value to PHP (web service) using the code below but it is always giving me the following output

[image]

In the PHP file I have the following code which actually receives the array and output the total structure with values:

```
<?php    
  $messages = $_POST['messages'];
  print_r($messages);
?>
```

Probably the problem is PHP is unable to read the array I am sending; may be because I am sending it from C#.

Could you please tell me how to send the array properly so that the PHP web service can read this.

FYI: I don't have the authority to edit any code in the web service end.

My Full C# Code

```
string[] str = { "num" ,  "Hello World" };

string url = "http://localhost/a/cash.php";

HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( url );

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string postData ;//= "keyword=moneky";
       postData = "&messages[]=" + str;

byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

  using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

MessageBox.Show(responseString);
```

Comment: Why don't you json encode from C# and then pass it to PHP, PHP can then decode it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I mentioned in my question I don't have any permission to edit codes in the web service end, or I can't even ask to change any code. The web service I am trying to work with doesn't expect any json encoded code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found the right solution myself after lots of trial and error. Here's the code in case if somebody needs:

I had to use dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myarray =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

    myarray .Add("0", "Number1");
    myarray .Add("1", "Hello World");
```

And then

```
string str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myarray);
```

Then my rest of the codes :

```
string url = "http://localhost/a/cash.php";

HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( url );

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

 string postData = "keyword=moneky";
        postData += "&messages[]=" + str;

 byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

 httpWReq.Method = "POST";
 httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

 using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

MessageBox.Show(responseString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your C# code:

**Old code**

```
string postData ;//= "keyword=moneky";
postData = "&messages[]=" + str;
```

**New code**

```
string postData = "";
foreach (string oneString in str) {
   postData += "messages[]=" + oneString + "&";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the op's answer works, I found the resulting string not so well formed (I really didn't like that `Environment.NewLine`), so for anyone out there still trying to figure out this, the following piece of code will do the trick for any amount of postData parameters, even if some of those parameters are arrays or lists, :

```
string[] str = { "abc" ,  "sdfsdf" }
var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "keyword", "monkey" },
    { "messages", str}
};

// Serialize the postData dictionary into a string
string serializedPostData = string.Empty;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in postData)
{
    if (IsCollection(pair.Value))
    {
        foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)pair.Value)
        {
            //%5B%5D is encoding for []
            serializedPostData += Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Key) + "%5B%5D=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(item)) + "&";
        }
    }
    else if (IsDate(pair.Value))
    {
        serializedPostData += Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Key) + "=" +
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(((DateTime)pair.Value).ToString("o")) + "&";
    }
    else
    {
        serializedPostData += Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Key) + "=" +
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(pair.Value)) + "&";
    }
}
serializedPostData = serializedPostData.TrimEnd('&');
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializedPostData);
```

The rest of the http call should work fine with the op's code. Below is the code for the IsCollection and IsDate methods:

```
private static bool IsCollection(object obj)
{
    bool isCollection = false;

    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    if (!typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(objType) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(objType))
    {
        isCollection = true;
    }

    return isCollection;
}

private static bool IsDate(object obj)
{
    bool isDate = false;

    if (typeof(DateTime) == obj.GetType() || typeof(DateTimeOffset) == obj.GetType())
    {
        isDate = true;
    }

    return isDate;
}
```

In my case this code will run in a SQL CLR C# Function, this is why I used only libraries available supported by SQL, thus my use of Uri.EscapeDataString instead of the more common HttpUtility.UrlEncode), but it works just fine.